# Is superfetch configurable?

Tags: windows-10, memory, compression, superfetch

Superfetch in Windows 10 works out many things and the concerning things for this question are

1) pre-load user's *preferred* programs for better experience.
2) manage memory compression.

Do pre-loaded programs hinder when a program which probably needs more than the available memory during **startup** and **runtime** ?

If yes then is there a way to turn off the preloading but keep the memory compression work in background ?

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: memory compression in Windows 10 cannot be configured, I don't even believe it can be turned off, without turning off other features resulting in worst performance.  Why exactly do you want to disable preloading?

Comment: @Ramhound Preloading slows my boot time as it starts as soon as I log in my PC. and look at this : https://i.imgur.com/WmXsW0N.png

Comment: Also I use variety of apps over time so pre-loading does not seem to be of great help over time.